# How do I parse an xml dictionary with XML::LibXML

Tags: perl

How do I parse an xml dictionary with XML::LibXML

At least I think it's called a dictionary.  I'm not finding good resources describing:

1. this XML format
2. XML::LibXML.  Perldoc doesn't even mention findvalue or textContent which I found on StackOverflow instead.

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Clippings</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Abbreviation</key>
            <string>;adeb</string>
            <key>Creation Date</key>
            <string>2017-04-22T22:02:32Z</string>
            <key>DateLastUsed</key>
            <string>2021-05-21T13:53:20Z</string>
            <key>Label</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Modification Date</key>
            <string>2018-04-30T18:16:36Z</string>
            <key>Option</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Plain Text</key>
            <string>print STDERR "(debug ⌘) $_\n" for @⌘;</string>
            <key>SortOrder</key>
            <string>1</string>
            <key>TotUsed</key>
            <integer>579</integer>
            <key>uuidString</key>
            <string>96707AF9-E9C4-4770-A930-B6889C354243</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Abbreviation</key>
            <string>;ahtml</string>
            <key>DateLastUsed</key>
            <string>2016-03-09T15:50:43Z</string>
            <key>Modification Date</key>
            <string>2016-05-18T09:35:49Z</string>
            <key>Option</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Plain Text</key>
            <string>print "(debug) Enter to continue:\n";
my $debug = &lt;STDIN&gt;;</string>
            <key>Service</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>SortOrder</key>
            <string>130</string>
            <key>TotUsed</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>uuidString</key>
            <string>E74E6ADC-7BE3-493B-AD1E-32729CAB2B77</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>sortOrderForThisSet</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>theAbbsFilePath</key>
    <string>/Users/user/path/to/file</string>
    <key>unsavedChanges</key>
    <false/>
    <key>uuidCheckDone</key>
    <string>yes</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So far, trying this perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = '/Users/user/path/to/file';

use XML::LibXML;

# Parse the XML
my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);

for my $entry ($xml->findnodes('//dict')) {
    my $key = $entry->findvalue('@key');
    my $value = $entry->textContent;

    print "$key = $value";
}
```

The value prints all the values together, while the key doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: Documentation is broken up into a bunch of pages, some of which you have discovered.  But here is a very useful [guide](https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) (written by the author of another, older, XML library).  There are also many posts on SO, some with summaries and guides.

Comment: The question doesn't say what you need from/of this document ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's address your absolutely false claim that "*Perldoc doesn't even mention findvalue or textContent*".

Document nodes are documented in [XML::LibXML::Document](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Document). The following is almost the very first thing that document says:

> It inherits all functions from [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Node) as specified in the DOM specification.

Element nodes are documented in [XML::LibXML::Element](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Element). The following is the very first thing that document says:

> The class inherits from [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Node). The documentation for Inherited methods is not listed here.

Both [`findvalue`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Node#findvalue) and [`textContent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Node#textContent) are documented in [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Node).

---

On to the actual problem.

Whoever designed that XML schema was told to use XML, but clearly didn't understand XML. It's bad even for a schema to encode arbitrary data structures like JSON. Whoever designed it only intended for the data to be converted into a different format before being used. The following does this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say state );

use Carp              qw( croak );
use Types::Serialiser qw( );
use XML::LibXML       qw( );

sub qname {
   my ($node) = @_;
   my $ns   = $node->namespaceURI();
   my $name = $node->nodeName();
   return defined($ns) ? "{$ns}$name" : $name;
}

sub deserialize_array {
   my ($array_node) = @_;
   return [ map { deserialize_value($_) } $array_node->findnodes("*") ];
}

sub deserialize_dict {
   my ($dict_node) = @_;

   my $dict = {};
   my @children = $dict_node->findnodes("*");
   while (@children) {
      my $key_node = shift(@children);
      qname($key_node) eq "key"
         or croak("Expected key");

      my $val_node = shift(@children)
         or croak("Expected value");

      my $key = $key_node->textContent();
      my $val = deserialize_value($val_node);
      $dict->{$key} = $val;
   }

   return $dict;
}

sub deserialize_value {
   my ($val_node) = @_;

   state $deserializers = {
      string  => sub { $_[0]->textContent() },
      integer => sub { 0 + $_[0]->textContent() },
      real    => sub { 0 + $_[0]->textContent() },
      true    => sub { $Types::Serialiser::true },
      false   => sub { $Types::Serialiser::false },
      data    => sub { croak("data values not currently supported"); },
      date    => sub { croak("date values not currently supported"); },
      array   => \&deserialize_array,
      dict    => \&deserialize_dict,
   };

   my $val_type = qname($val_node);
   my $deserializer = $deserializers->{$val_type}
      or croak("Unrecognized value type \"$val_type\"");

   return $deserializer->($val_node);
}

sub deserialize_doc {
   my ($doc) = @_;
   my @children = $doc->documentElement->findnodes("*");
   croak("Root element has too few children") if @children == 0;
   croak("Root element has too many children") if @children > 1;
   return deserialize_value($children[0]);
}

{
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $ARGV[0] );
   my $prop_list = deserialize_doc($doc);
   ...
}
```

If you dump `$prop_list`, it looks something like

```perl
$prop_list = {
  "Clippings" => [
    {
      "Creation Date" => "2017-04-22T22:02:32Z",
      "TotUsed" => 579,
      "DateLastUsed" => "2021-05-21T13:53:20Z",
      "Abbreviation" => ";adeb",
      "Plain Text" => "print STDERR \"(debug \x{2318}) \$_\\n\" for \@\x{2318};",
      "uuidString" => "96707AF9-E9C4-4770-A930-B6889C354243",
      "Modification Date" => "2018-04-30T18:16:36Z",
      "SortOrder" => 1,
      "Label" => "",
      "Option" => ""
    },
    {
      "Option" => "",
      "Modification Date" => "2016-05-18T09:35:49Z",
      "SortOrder" => 130,
      "uuidString" => "E74E6ADC-7BE3-493B-AD1E-32729CAB2B77",
      "Plain Text" => "print \"(debug) Enter to continue:\\n\";\nmy \$debug = <STDIN>;",
      "Abbreviation" => ";ahtml",
      "Service" => "",
      "TotUsed" => 1,
      "DateLastUsed" => "2016-03-09T15:50:43Z"
    }
  ],
  "unsavedChanges" => $false,
  "sortOrderForThisSet" => 0,
  "uuidCheckDone" => "yes",
  "theAbbsFilePath" => "/Users/user/path/to/file"
};
```

The above was obtained using

```perl
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print(Data::Dumper->Dump(
   [ $Types::Serialiser::true, $Types::Serialiser::false, $prop_list ],
   [qw( true false prop_list )],
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found more info on findvalue and textContent with:
perldoc XML::LibXML::XPathContext

```
for my $entry ($xml->findnodes('//dict')) {
  use Data::Dumper::Simple;
  print STDERR "(debug) " . Dumper($entry);
```

revealed it's a:
XML::LibXML::Element
Which also has POD so you can use perldoc on it.

Here's the code I ended up with.  It's not a good solution for a lot of reasons, starting with it's still not properly reading the XML.  But, it works on a most basic level, and of course, I'm crunched for time.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;
use utf8;
use Encode;

binmode *STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';    # warning: global effect
binmode *STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $filename = $ENV{HOME} . '/TypeIt4Me/clippings.typeit4me.test-dev-input';

# Parse the XML
my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $filename );

# Iterate the entries
my %input_xml_hr;

for my $entry ( $xml->findnodes('//dict') ) {
    print "\n";
    my %hr;

    my @keys;
    my @vals;
    foreach my $key ( $entry->findnodes('key') ) {
        push @keys, $key->to_literal();
    }
    foreach my $string ( $entry->findnodes('string') ) {
        push @vals, $string->to_literal();
    }

    my $count_keys = scalar @keys;
    my $count_vals = scalar @vals;
    if ( $count_keys ne $count_vals ) {

        # print STDERR "[WARN] keys: $count_keys, vals: $count_vals\n";
        $hr{'WARN'} = "keys: $count_keys, vals: $count_vals";
    }

    foreach my $num ( 0 .. $#keys ) {
        my $key = $keys[$num];
        my $val = $vals[$num];
        $hr{$key} = encode_utf8 $val;
    }

    $input_xml_hr{ $hr{'Abbreviation'} } = $hr{'Plain Text'};
}

for my $key ( keys %input_xml_hr ) {
    print $key . " = " . decode_utf8 $input_xml_hr{$key} . "\n" if defined $input_xml_hr{$key};
}

print "\n";
```

Comment: That loop can be replaced with `@hr{@keys} = @vals;`

Comment: You're not using XML::LibXML::XPathContext at all, much less its findvalue and textContent. If you were using any, you'd be using the ones from XML::LibXML::Node.